# Notice: Undefined index: action in /opt/lampp/htdocs/contacts.php on line 6

Tags: php, html

I was developing one simple PHP script in window machine and was testing in xampp. I have completed it and its working fine in my windows machine. Now I have tried to move it in my centos 7 machine which also have xampp. Its giving me error like below

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in /opt/lampp/htdocs/contacts.php on line 6
```

My code for that function is like below

```
if($_GET['action']=="change_status" && $_GET['contact_id']>0 )

    {
        $upd_qry = "update contacts set status = ? where id=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $upd_qry);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_GET['status'],$_GET['contact_id']);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $_SESSION['msg']="11";
        header( "Location:contacts.php");
        exit;

    }
```

I have marked that similar errors in 1-2 more files too. I do not understanding why this happening. I have php 7.2 in my windows machine and in centos its 7.0
let me know if someone know what is wrong with it.
Thanks

Comment: How are you calling `contacts.php`? Is there a get parameter called `action`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$_GET['action']` does not exist, when you don't add it in the URL. You can work it around by adding a [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)-check

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="change_status" && $_GET['contact_id']>0 )

    {
        $upd_qry = "update contacts set status = ? where id=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $upd_qry);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_GET['status'],$_GET['contact_id']);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $_SESSION['msg']="11";
        header( "Location:contacts.php");
        exit;

    }
```